# Child UIView within root UIView squished for some reason, even though width is explicitly set in XIB

Tags: uiview, ios6

I have a simple app that has the following hierarchy:

- Root UIView (blank) - tied to the root view controller
- child UIView with a whole bunch of things on it - tied to a child view controller that the root view controller inserts upon viewDidLoad.

In the XIBs (separate xib for parent and child), both UIViews have the exact same dimensions (1004x768). However, for some reason, when it launches, there is a gap on the right side between the root UIView and child UIView. I proved this by importing QuartzCore and making the UIViews drawing colored borders around it. Please see the diagram I attached. Does anyone know why this occur? I even tried playing around with constraint priority (making the constraint resistent priority higher for the child), and it still doesn't work.

Would appreciate any tips to put in in the right direction.[image]

Comment: I have also tried: 1) wantsFullScreenLayout setting, 2) matching the child UIView frames to parent or application window frame, calling autoresizingMask = DISABLED in the child UIView, etc. None worked.

Comment: I solved my own problem -- instead of using imageview, do this: 1) make uiview in the xib 1024 in width instead of 1004, 2) use the backgroundColor function to make a background color based on an image pattern and send that message to the uiview.

Answer (score 0):

Root UIView is always managed by the window to have fullscreen size:

From the “View Management” section of the UIViewController Class Reference:

> If a view controller is owned by a window object, it acts as the
>   window’s root view controller. The view controller’s root view is
>   added as a subview of the window and resized to fill the window.